# Updating Django settings using manage.py command

Tags: python, django, configuration, django-admin

I am creating a Twitter bot and I have a couple of API Key's that I need to store to access the Twitter API. These API Key's need to be stored somewhere in the web server and, when I was looking at ways to do this, I thought of something else.

I went to Django's docs to see how to create a `manage.py` command and then made one, but now I still haven't found a way to make is change the Django's settings even though I've looked at quite a few websites, the best one was https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings.

I'll probably just make a `settings_local.py` file and store everything there, but I was wondering if it would be possible to do it with the `manage.py` command because I think that that would be a useful way to get everything working.

Here's my current code

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.conf import settings


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Configure the server with developer codes to allow for Twitter API connection."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        api_key = input("API Key: ")
        secret_key = input("Secret Key: ")

        settings.configure(TWITTER_API_KEY=api_key,
                           TWITTER_SECRET_KEY=secret_key)
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(
            "Successfully added your Twitter API_KEY and SECRET_KEY"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use environment variables?

example if you are using linux (bash).

```
~$ export API_KEY="my_api_key"
```

or store this on bashrc

On settings.py.

```
import os

TWITTER_API_KEY=os.getenv("API_KEY")
```

Comment: Simple suggestion yet very helpful!